# Python3 re negative lookahead like this

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to find a string which closet to `@@` like below

```
def get_closet(ss):
    m = re.search('(?<=@@)(.*)$', ss, re.I)
    if m:
        print('find')
        print(m.groups())
    else:
        print('not find')



str1 = '@@ AF @@ BV @@ CX @@ DDFFF'  # should return `DDFFF`
str2 = ' DDFFF'  # should return `DDFFF` 
for x in str1, str2:
    get_closet(x)
```

---

I find `m = re.search('((?!@@).)*$', ss, re.I|re.S)` but when input is `str1`,it will return `@ DDFFF` not `DDFFF`

Comment: How is `DDFFF` any closer to `@@` than say `CX`? Do you mean you want anything after the last `@@`?

Comment: Yes,I want to find out the last anything which not contain `@@` or end after the last `@@`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `(?:@@| )?([^@@ ]+)$`:

```
import re

print(re.findall('(?:@@| )?([^@@ ]+)$', '@@ AF @@ BV @@ CX @@ DDFFF'))
# ['DDFFF']
print(re.findall('(?:@@| )?([^@@ ]+)$', ' DDFFF'))
# ['DDFFF']
```

But, you don't necessarily need a regex:

```
def foo(string):
    try:
        return string[string.rindex('@@'):].strip('@@ ')
    except ValueError:  # if no @@
        return string.strip()

string = '@@ AF @@ BV @@ CX @@ DDFFF'
print(foo(string))
# 'DDFFF'
string = ' DDFFF'
print(foo(string))
# 'DDFFF'
```

Or even the more generic:

```
def foo(sep, string):
    try:
        return string[string.rindex(sep):].strip(sep + ' ')
    except ValueError:  # if no sep
        return string.strip()
```